# dictionary not properly called out in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a made a dictionary and tried to call out the value but I am getting value of the excel cell row number also along with the cell value. I only want the values of the respective cells. Here's what I am getting while I run the code. I have attached the images. And why does it show dtype: object. Am I missing something in the code? or something is wrongly written.

[image]

[image]

```
def Trainreadin(actfile, actsheetname):
    frame = Input.xclReadIn(actfile, actsheetname)
dict = {'resistance':
[']resistance_name(word)_A(N)_B(N/(km/h))_C(N/(km/h)2)_windT(km/h)_windB(km/h)', 'table']

outputdict = {key: framehandle.value_readin(value) for (key, value) in dict.items()}
outputdict["resistance_A"] = outputdict["resistance"][1]
outputdict["resistance_B"] = outputdict["resistance"][2] * 3.6
print(outputdict["resistance_A"])
return outputdict
```

Comment: You're missing the `}` at the end of the dictionary. Also, don't name your variable `dict`, that's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: All the lines from `dict =` need to be indented so they're inside the function.

Comment: What is `framehandle`? Is that supposed to be `frame`?

Comment: I made the changes as you said @Barmar. It is a frame. But why it is showing me the cell row number together ? Can you please help me with that.

Comment: Because that's what `Input.xclReadIn()` is returning.

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of it ? Or any other solution, as it gives me error when I use this data for further calculation.